# Composing separate jQuery object in one

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

This is code sample(in coffescript):

```
$el1 = $ '#el1' # those name are dummy, just for example
$el2 = $ '#el2'

# I want to compose those objects into one 
# Result should be equal to: 
$("#el1, #el2")

# Something like:
$([el1, el2]) # this isn't work
```

How I can do that?

Comment: maybe you could use a class as selector...

Comment: You can use startswith selector if the ids starts with the same name like this $('[id^="el"]') http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Or find another way to refer to them (e.g. if they are all `input`s within a specific `div`, go for `$("#theDiv input")`. We can't really suggest more than that without seeing more code

Comment: The reason why I doesn't want to add some class because as for me it is bad practice to add classes that doesn't have some logical meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what you're trying to do but I think you're starting with:

```
$el1 = $('#some_id')
$el2 = $('#some_other_id')
#...
```

and you want to combine `$el1` and `$el2` into another jQuery object that acts as though you'd said:

```
$els = $('#some_id, #some_other_id')
```

so that you can works with `$el1` and `$el2` at the same time. That sort of thing is easy to do using [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$els = $el1.add($el2)
# or if it is more convenient:
$els = $().add($el1).add($el2);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Uu2G3/1/

I don't know if working with `$els` will be more efficient that working with `[$el1,$el2]` though, jQuery will end up looping through all the DOM elements inside `$els` anyway so I doubt it will make much difference if you do the looping or if jQuery does it. OTOH, collecting the elements into `$els` will probably make things easier and clearer for you.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand that i look just for a way to combine a jQuery objects:)). Can you provide an idea how I can improve my question?

Comment: @kharandziuk: The `$([el1, el2]) # this isn't work` change you made was a good improvement. A simple live example of the sorts of things you want to do usually helps quite a bit, jsfiddle.net and jsbin.com are good tools for providing editable examples; posting on an English site when English isn't your first language can be difficult, examples help get past some of the language problems.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to give those elements a class name. Then you can use

```
$(".theClassName").on('blur', () ->
    # do something
)
```

Comment: OP has edited to say adding a class is not possible. Leaving this answer here as it may help others. If that's incorrect behaviour let me know